# How to programatically get an element that is selected/highlighted?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, internet-explorer-11, radeditor

I am working on an application based on ASP.NET, running in IE11.

One part of the application makes use of (Telerik) RadEditor to create a layout of several items. I am selecting the items (dom elements) as seen in the below image. I selected the top item, then the bottom.

[image: Elements selected]

Is there a way (in JavaScript) to retrieve the elements (or even a single element)? I need to select the element(s) based on something other than the RadEditor object.

To be clear, I can't use `editor.getSelectedElement();` (it doesn't do what I want). `document.activeElement;`, `$(":focus");`, `document.hasFocus();`, and `editor.getSelection()` all don't return the right objects. There also is no css class or property being applied, so they aren't any help here.

Comment: Have you tried getSelection()??  https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/editor/client-side-programming/methods/getselection

Comment: Yes and it does the same as getSelectedElement(), I'll add it in.